# Scala API Abstract Value Member

Tags: scala

The Scala API lists something called Abstract Value Members under some classes and traits.  What are these things and how do they differ from what the API lists as Concrete Values Members?

Comment: Read this: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html

Comment: I understand in general what the basics abstracts are, which is what the link you provided describes.  I am looking for a description of the abstracts that are defined in the API under various traits and classes and specifically referred to as Abstract Value Members.  This aspect is not covered in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abstract value has a name and a type but no value. This value has to be provided by a concrete val definition in a subclass. In contrast, concrete value members do have a name, type and value defined. It is as simple as that. Scala' abstraction mechanisms are more general than Java's.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is covered in the link provided by @I.K. http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/abstract-members.html

Abstract Value Members are simple abstract members, i.e. members that don't have a value. Note that they are NOT necessarily `val`s but `def`s are included as well.